# using getData on a spreadsheet retaining font formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script in my Code.hs file:

```
function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('17zMVbzevOV7HNpGIjkFKi_l_kUeuX7NX2jG5GIL8Jow')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

However, if a cell contains:

- "this **is** a test"

where "is" is in **bold**, when I get the data in the spreadsheet, I have:

- "this is a test"

Without bolding.
Is there a way to get the text contents *and* the IN-string formatting (NOT the cell formatting) somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to get the in-string formatting. The closest I can find is a [Range method getFontStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontstyle)

However this returns 'italic' if the whole string is italic, and 'normal' if it isn't. It does not identify bold, nor does it identify if part of the string is bold or italic.

Answer (score 0):

The Spreadsheet Service of Google Apps Script doesn't includes yet a method to handle the format for cell content parts. At this time one alternative is to use copyTo(destination) or copyTo(destination, options) from the [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).